# Month without leading zeros in Android

Tags: android, simpledateformat

Is there a way to format a Month without leading zeros in Java/Android?

I got this:

```
mTitleText.setText(String.format("Pick Date Time: %tm/%te/%tY %tk:%02d",
                mTime,mTime,mTime,mTime,minute));
```

And it returns 02/12/2012 13:23 when I want it to return 2/12/2012 13:23.

Comment: Couldn't you just chop off the leading 0 with a substring? Or do you want a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 39):

For those interested in avoiding the lengthy [JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Date mTime = new Date();  
String text = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy hh:mm").format(mTime);
```

Using `M` instead of `MM` and `d` instead of `dd` will render the day of the month and month without leading zeros if possible.

Comment: You can also remove one of the `h` in hours to remove the preceding zero there.

Answer (score 3):

Using Java 8 [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), it can be achieved by using single characters instead of the pairs used to denote each of day, month, hour, minutes and seconds.

**"yyyy/M/d H:m:s"** will allow parsing date and time without zero padded values.

**"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"** requires(expects) zero-padding else will throw a **DateTimeParseException**.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

//start class and method scope
try {
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/M/d H:m");
LocalDateTime.parse(stringToBeParsed, formatter);
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
//Log error in parsing, exit program, abort current execution, return null response for API call, shutdown system, whatever.
}
//end class and method scope
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `String.format()`, can you use the `SimpleDateFormat` class?  It will do what you want, but without seeing more of your code I can't tell if you have a Date or Calendar object you can use.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now()
             .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu HH:mm" ) )
```

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

In the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class, define a formatting pattern using single character codes for month and/or day-of-month rather than double-character codes.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu HH:mm" );
```

Get the current moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

Generate a string.

```
String output = zdt.format( f )
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` is good, but you can also do it like this:

`mTitleText.setText(String.format("Pick Date Time: %s/%1$te/%$1tY %$1tk:%02d",
                mTime.getMonth()+1,mTime,minute));`