# Converting time to local time

Tags: java, android

I want to convert time from RSS feed into local time. Here is how it looks in RSS feed:

```
<pubDate>Sat, 16 Dec 2017 22:13:00 +0000</pubDate>
```

What I want to do is getting that 22:13 from there and converting it into local time. Here is the code:

```
if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                                SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US);
                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                cal.setTime(inputFormat.parse(currentTextContent.substring(5, 16)));
                                SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.US); // 01-12
                                outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                                String postTime = outputFormat.format(currentTextContent.substring(17, 22));
                                rssFeedModelItem.setPubDate(outputFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
                                System.out.println("Time"+" "+postTime);
                                rssFeedModelItem.setPubTime(postTime);
                            }
```

With this code app is giving no Internet connection error which is strange. After removing this:

```
String postTime = outputFormat.format(currentTextContent.substring(17, 22));
```

And changing

```
rssFeedModelItem.setPubTime(postTime);
```

into this:

```
rssFeedModelItem.setPubTime(currentTextContent.substring(17, 22));
```

the app is working but showing RSS time. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26807905/5958058) solution but it's not worked. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to parse the whole date with this pattern

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't need whole date. I only need to convert the time to another timezone. It's not possible?

Comment: After you have parsed the date, you can use another formatter to print whatever you want in whatever timezone you need